# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 - How to check API response is in JSON format or not

Tags: wso2, sequence, wso2-esb

How to validate the API response is in JSON or in HTML format using outsequence in wso2 ESB 5.0.0
I want to alter the response code if response is in HTML format.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use `switchMediator` with something like that below.
But be aware and dont try to use `<log level =" full ">` on HTML, unless you have proper messageBuilder and messageFormater for that content type. In default WSO2 ESB tryes to convert using xml builder, and it will ended with error. I tried this on wso2ei 6.5.0 but i believe it should work on esb 5.0.0.

```
<switch source="$trp:Content-Type">
     <case regex="^(application\/(json|x-javascript))(;.*)?$">
        <log>
           <property name="Looks like Json format" expression="$trp:Content-type"/>
        </log>
     </case>
     <case regex="^(text\/html)(;.*)?$">
        <!--Don't log full, unless you have proper axis2.xml configuration for that contentType-->
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="Looks like HTML format" expression="$trp:Content-type"/>
        </log>
     </case>
     <default>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="Unknown format" expression="$trp:Content-type"/>
        </log>
     </default>
 </switch>
```